# Saving a value from a drop down to a variable PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to save the value selected in the date drop down box to a variable '$AvailabilityID' which is retrieved on the next page. The drop down box is populated from the MYSQL table bs_availability. From what I've read I need to use Javascript but really no idea how to do it.

Any help appreciated.

```
<?php
    //current URL of the Page. cart_update.php redirects back to this URL
    $current_url = base64_encode("http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

        $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT SessionType, SessionName, SessionCost, SessionID FROM bs_session
    GROUP BY SessionName ORDER BY SessionType ASC;");
        if ($results) { 
            //output results from database
            while($obj = $results->fetch_object())
            {
                $availabilityresults = $mysqli->query("SELECT * From bs_availability WHERE sessionID = ".$obj->SessionID.";");

                echo '<tr>'; 
                echo '<form method="post" action="cart_update.php">';
                echo '<td>'.$obj->SessionName.'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$obj->SessionType.'</td>';
                echo '<td><select name="date">';
               //While loop to populate drop down with table data
               while($objdate = $availabilityresults->fetch_object())
                {
                    echo '<option value ="'.$objdate->AvailabilityID.'">'.$objdate->Date.'</option>';
                }
                echo '</select>';
                echo '</td>';
                echo '<td>Price '.$currency.$obj->SessionCost.' <button class="add_to_cart">Add To Cart</button></td>';
                echo '</tr>';
                echo '<input type="hidden" name="SessionID" value="'.$obj->SessionID.'" />';
                echo '<input type="hidden" name="AvailabilityID" value="'.$objdate->AvailabilityID.'" />';
                echo '<input type="hidden" name="type" value="add" />';
                echo '<input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="'.$current_url.'" />';
                echo '</form>';
                echo '</div>';
            }

    }
    ?>
```

EDIT: This code is the cart_update.php. So when Add to Basket is pressed this script is run using the $SessionID from the selected item but I also need the AvailabiltyID of the chosen date so that I can run the right query to add the right date to the basket.

```
<?php
session_start(); //start session
include_once("config.php"); //include config file

//empty cart by distroying current session
if(isset($_GET["emptycart"]) && $_GET["emptycart"]==1)
{
    $return_url = base64_decode($_GET["return_url"]); //return url
    session_destroy();
    header('Location:'.$return_url);
}

//add item in shopping cart
if(isset($_POST["type"]) && $_POST["type"]=='add')
{
    $SessionID   = filter_var($_POST["SessionID"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //product code
    $AvailabilityID = filter_var($_POST["AvailabilityID"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //product code
    $product_qty    = filter_var($_POST["product_qty"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT); //product code
    $return_url     = base64_decode($_POST["return_url"]); //return url

    //limit quantity for single product
    if($product_qty > 10){
        die('<div align="center">This demo does not allowed more than 10 quantity!<br /><a href="http://sanwebe.com/assets/paypal-shopping-cart-integration/">Back To Products</a>.</div>');
    }
    console.log($availabilityID);
    //MySqli query - get details of item from db using product code    
    $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT SessionName, SessionCost FROM bs_session WHERE SessionID=$SessionID LIMIT 1");
    //$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT bs_session.SessionName, bs_availability.Date, bs_session.SessionCost FROM bs_availability INNER JOIN bs_session ON bs_session.SessionID=bs_availability.SessionID WHERE bs_availability.AvailabilityID=$AvailabilityID LIMIT 1");
    $obj = $results->fetch_object();

    if ($results) { //we have the product info 

        //prepare array for the session variable
        $new_product = array(array('name'=>$obj->SessionName, 'code'=>$SessionID, 'date'=>$obj->Date, 'price'=>$obj->SessionCost));

        if(isset($_SESSION["products"])) //if we have the session
        {
            $found = false; //set found item to false

            foreach ($_SESSION["products"] as $cart_itm) //loop through session array
            {
                if($cart_itm["code"] == $SessionID){ //the item exist in array

                    $product[] = array('name'=>$cart_itm["name"], 'code'=>$cart_itm["code"], 'date'=>$cart_itm["date"], 'price'=>$cart_itm["price"]);
                    $found = true;
                }else{
                    //item doesn't exist in the list, just retrive old info and prepare array for session var
                    $product[] = array('name'=>$cart_itm["name"], 'code'=>$cart_itm["code"], 'date'=>$cart_itm["date"], 'price'=>$cart_itm["price"]);
                }
            }

            if($found == false) //we didn't find item in array
            {
                //add new user item in array
                $_SESSION["products"] = array_merge($product, $new_product);
            }else{
                //found user item in array list, and increased the quantity
                $_SESSION["products"] = $product;
            }

        }else{
            //create a new session var if does not exist
            $_SESSION["products"] = $new_product;
        }

    }

    //redirect back to original page
    header('Location:'.$return_url);
}

//remove item from shopping cart
if(isset($_GET["removep"]) && isset($_GET["return_url"]) && isset($_SESSION["products"]))
{
    $SessionID   = $_GET["removep"]; //get the product code to remove
    $return_url     = base64_decode($_GET["return_url"]); //get return url


    foreach ($_SESSION["products"] as $cart_itm) //loop through session array var
    {
        if($cart_itm["code"]!=$SessionID){ //item does,t exist in the list
            $product[] = array('name'=>$cart_itm["name"], 'code'=>$cart_itm["code"], 'qty'=>$cart_itm["qty"], 'price'=>$cart_itm["price"]);
        }

        //create a new product list for cart
        $_SESSION["products"] = $product;
    }

    //redirect back to original page
    header('Location:'.$return_url);
}
```

Comment: We need far more information.  Do you want to save when the user saves the form? If so, then this is simple, no javascript required.

Comment: If the dropdown is part of a form, when the form is submitted it will be available in the `$_POST` array under the name you gave the dropdown element.

Comment: How is this form submitted? You might need to add an <input> of type Submit. Then `$_POST['date']` should contain the selected entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP, this is done through the POST array on your cart_update.php page:

```
if (isset($_POST['date'])){
    $AvailabilityID = $_POST['date'];
}
```

You could also change the existing add to cart button to give it a name that will appear in the POST array:

```
echo '<td>Price '.$currency.$obj->SessionCost.' <button class="add_to_cart" name="add_to_cart">Add To Cart</button></td>';
```

This is often used as a check on the processing page, with an if block around all of the processing code.

```
if (isset($_POST['add_to_cart'])){

    //all processing code here

}
```

Comment: Realised I was structuring wrong and your solution works great now. Cheers muchly

Answer (score -1):

Just use the POST Variable `$_POST['date']` which holds the selected option value.